# I need to generate Liquibase Change-set for my JPA entities. How can I do that?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, liquibase

I have tried the following

`liquibase:generateChangeLog` - It generated the change log from my db.I need to generate the `change-log` from my `JPA entities`.

`liquibase:diff` - It generates the change log for the difference between my db and `JPA` entities. I cannot say that my db is always empty and I want to generate the create scripts which can be applied on fresh db.

How can I use `Liquibase` to generate the scripts based on my `JPA` entities only ?

Note : I am ok in providing the details about my db such as url,driver etc

Answer (score 19):

If your IDE of choice is IntelliJ IDEA, I'd recommend using the [JPA Buddy](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15075-jpa-buddy) plugin to do this. It can generate Liquibase changelogs by comparing your Java model to the target DB.

So if your DB is empty, you'll get a changelog that describes your whole model. But it is also useful to keep your evolving model and your changelogs in sync.

Once you have it installed and have Liquibase as your Maven/Gradle dependency, you can generate a changelog like this:
[image: generating a liquibase changelog with JPA Buddy]

Comment: Is there a way to make JPA Buddy show the changelog in YAML?

Comment: Sadly, this is now a premium JPA Buddy feature!

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [liquibase-hibernate-plugin](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a schema with persistence properties according to [Database Schema Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro005.htm) and then use the Liquibase [generateChangeLog](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html) command.

Comment: Will it generate my changelog from the entities?

Comment: It will generate Schema from entites through JPA and the changelog using liquibase afterwards.

Comment: Is it possible to create change log from the generated schema ? Or do we have to apply the schema to a db and then generate change log from it?

Comment: I think it is not possible. But if you do not want to create a real database you could work around using a h2 memory database.