# liquibase and jpa buddy using gradle

Tags: jpa, gradle, liquibase

I'm trying to use JPA Buddy to generate changelogs from my entities.

In this answer I can see the Liquibase option:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66516541/6047129

[image]

But in my IDE thats all I got:

[image]

I'm missing some gradle or liquibse configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I had liquibase dependency declared as:

```
liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.11.0'
```

As JPA Buddy scans the project dependencies for possible integrations, I needed to change the liquibase dependency to:

```
implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.11.0'
```